# Delay invoke of Completable function after concatWith is success(RxJava/RxKotlin)

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-kotlin

I am looking a way to delay invoke of an Completable function after first Completable is success and all logic is finished.

```
fun invokeSomeLogic(): Completable {
  return firstCompletable() ----> lets assume is success
  .concatWith(secondCompletable()) ---> lets assume is success
  .concatWith(thirdCompletable()) // THIS IS THE FUNCTION I WANT TO DELAY
  .onErrorResumeNext {...}

}
```

I want to delay the third for 2 sec after the second one is finished with success. When I was debugging and set some breakpoints on third function it seems that third fun is invoked regardless of second fun. Is this a normal behaviour of concatWith?
Appreciate any help!

Comment: How is the `thirdCompletable` implemented? Also methods are invoked because you `()` is an indication of method invocation. You could have just listed thirdCompletable() without any Rx and it would still get invoked.

Comment: Third one returns Completable, it is like: return Completable.fromObservable(...)

Comment: Interesting, what I tried now is Completable.deffer{third fun} and it works as intended. Is this function triggered even if error occurs on second fun? Thanks!
It seems there is some race condition in codebase so this helped to fix a bug.

Comment: If you are using `concatWith`, then `defer` won't run if the preceding completable failed.

Comment: What if we use andThen(Completable.deffer{third fun} )?

Comment: The same. Please check out the javadoc of the operators.